# Can two different CA's/End Entities in different PKI's have the same asymmetric key pair?

Tags: public-key, keys, certificates

Example: $X$ and $Y$ have the same asymmetric key pair. 
$X$ communicates with $A$ and gives it's PubKey to $A$.

So, $A$ has the PubKey of $X$ which also happens to be the PubKey/PrivKey of $Y$. 
Now intentionally or by chance, can $A$ intercept and read the signed messages of $Y$?

If this can happen, does this not make the PKI vulnerable?

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking. Can you edit to add more detail?

Comment: "Can" is ambiguous: is that from the standpoint of having the PKI work (and then is that from a mathematical or security/legal standpoint?). Or are you asking if this can happen by chance/or accident?

Comment: Sure, but what is the chance?

Comment: Are the keypair in question used for encryption or signing?

Comment: what will be the case for each of these transactions i.e. signing and encryption?

Comment: @Yash, for signing, as no encryption is involed, anybody can intercept and read it, but will be confused as to which of X and Y signed it (because they have the same pubkey). For encryption, it's the public key, so nobody can easily read it. Only X and Y can read it, because they've the same private key. I suggest we move this to chat, I'll find you.

Comment: You say "Now A has the PuKey of X which also happens to be the PuKey/PrKey of Y." but this is not true, the PubKey of X is simply the PubKey of Y, not his Private one at the same time, if they really have the same key pair.

Comment: The word "public" represents, that it is assumed **everyone** knows it (at least anyone taking part in the PKI). So it's completely irrelevant if $X$ tells anyone his pblic key. Also, if $X$ and $Y$ are different parties who are not working together, then the chance of having the same keypair (by chance) is very small, e.g. $1$ divided by the number of atoms in the observable universe or less (which is around $1/10^{80}\approx 1/2^{266}$). This doesn't qualify as *impossible* but it's close enough to be unrealistic for every practical purpose.

Comment: @DannyNiu, how can we move to chat?

Comment: @tylo it means that it can happen that different CA's/EE's in dofferent PKI's have the same asymmetric key pair. Also either of the keys can be used as PuK or PrK, which means that in this case A may have the PuK of X which happens to be PrK of Y?? I would also like to know if there is any record of which keys have already been issued so that there is no redundancy in issuing newer keys which would make the PKI more secure?

Comment: @Yash, I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: @Yash Yes, it could happen - *if and only if* we disregard phsyical limitations. But an attacker could also just guess your private key without any other knowledge - which would be a more severe problem than having 2 unrelated people with the same key. And that is true for every single public key ever created. I fail to see what your actual goal is - because there is no problem.

Answer (score 1):

> If this can happen, does this not make the PKI vulnerable?

if by chance they tend to generate THE SAME key (p,q) and private parameter (d), indeed they could read/sign each other's messages

However - it is the same probability as with guessing any key - choosing a random value from the whole set, there's a small probability the chosen value will be the key. The keyspace (say 128 bit for symmetric / 2048 bit for assymetric keys) should be big enough that the probability is negligible.

> Now A has the PuKey of X which also happens to be the PuKey/PrKey of Y

A shall have no access to the private key of Y. As it happens, that's not problem of PKI, that's problem of Y not protecting its key